# Spivak chain rule proof possible errata?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

In the following proof by Spivak, it in the marked part of the image, shouldn't the equation read

$$=[g(f(x))-g(b)-\mu(f(x)-f(a))]-\mu(\varphi(x))$$

rather than

$$=[g(f(x))-g(b)-\mu(f(x)-f(a))]+\mu(\varphi(x))$$

I thought by linearity, since the $\varphi(x)$ is subtracted, that we would also subtract $\mu(\varphi(x))$

[image]

Comment: $-\mu(-\varphi(x)) = \mu(\varphi(x)).$ (You admit you are aware $\mu$ is linear.)

Comment: @WillM. Ah of course that was so obvious thank you so much